# Seeking shapefile of hexagons that covers world?

Tags: shapefile, data, hexagonal-grid, h3

I'd like a persistent .shp that covers the world in hexagons (preferably of a decently small area)–does anybody know where I could find something like this, or perhaps what software I could use to make one? MMQGIS freezes whenever I try to export something of this size.

Comment: Could you specify how small "decently small" is? Also, what projection will you be using?

Comment: ArcGIS Users can use http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/05/06/a-new-tool-for-creating-sampling-hexagons/ Create Hexagon Tessellation http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=03388990d3274160afe240ac54763e57

Comment: have you checked this https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b073c9aa774649f6b8122631334b58f5#overview? I did not find how to download them as shapefile, but it maybe it is possible

Comment: also see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310555/using-uber-h3-from-qgis

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uber has recently developed [**H3**, which is a geospatial indexing system using multiple hexagonal grids of different sizes organized hierarchically](https://github.com/uber/h3).

There is an `R` package called [h3r](https://github.com/scottmmjackson/h3r) that makes it easy to work with Uber's h3 in `R`. There are also `Java` and `Java-script` [bindings of H3](https://uber.github.io/h3/#/documentation/community/bindings).

[image]

Answer (score 14):

It's probably easiest for you to create your own hexagonal grid shapefile. Many GIS have built-in tools for creating hexagonal grids of any desired resolution and orientation. For example, in the cross-platform and open-source GIS [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml), for which I am a developer, you can use the *[Create Hexagonal Vector Grid](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/CreateHexagonalVectorGrid.html)* tool to create a hex-grid shapefile for the world using a countries shapefile as the base.

[image]

You can specify any desired resolution and whether the grid should be vertical or horizontal (a consideration when working with hex-tessellation). In fact, I enjoy working with hexagonal grids so much that I also wrote a tool for Whitebox GAT that performs [hexagonal binning](http://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/hexbinning-in-whitebox-gat/) (like a hex heatmap). The following is an example for density of world cities:

[image]

Comment: Simple and brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

Note that it is impossible to partition a sphere into hexagons only; such a partition must contain some non-hexagonal cells. For example, every resolution of Uber's `H3` contains exactly 12 pentagons amongst the hexagons.

You can generate .shp files of hexagonal global grids for all or part of the globe using the free software `DGGRID` ( http://www.discreteglobalgrids.org/software/ ). If you're an `R` user you can use `dggridR` ( https://github.com/r-barnes/dggridR ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use QGIS to create hexagons, but I think Uber H3 is a better solution for most analysis. Here is a [link](https://www.gislounge.com/using-qgis-create-hexbin-map-gisp-registrations/) to a tutorial for QGIS.

Comment: just to be clear, the tutorial is about how to create generic hex maps in Qgis, not how to use H3 hex grids in Qgis.