# Using Uber H3 hexagon grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis, hexagon-binning, h3, uber

How can I create a spatial binning similar to or directly using Uber [h3](/questions/tagged/h3) from QGIS UI?

Are there plugins available to achieve the desired task?

Comment: If you explain how Uber H3 does spatial binning, you're more likely to get a useful answer. Otherwise the only people who can answer would be those who know both Uber H3 *and* QGIS, which may be a very small number of people.

Comment: It looks like https://eng.uber.com/h3/ and mostly consists of hexagons. A solution in python would also be great.

Answer (score 7):

You can play with it using my #30DayMapChallenge hexagon demo https://github.com/ThomasG77/30DayMapChallenge/blob/master/day4_hexagons/data/h3-processing.py

Except the fact I do no use an UI, I combine both QGIS and Uber H3 Python library.

I clearly do not use all parts of the H3 Python library. I suppose the example could help you getting started.

**Edit 2022-05-20**

New QGIS plugin ["H3 Toolkit"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/h3_toolkit/) unrelated to me but doing more or less the same. Although we provide the link, install it directly from QGIS plugins list.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. You're implementation was very helpful. I adapted it to generate hex grids for the extent of an input layer: https://github.com/maphew/code/blob/master/gis/qgis/h3-grid-from-layer.py

Comment: Thanks mat wilkie. I cant run the script.I get the error:  File "<string>", line 55, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: At https://github.com/maphew/code/blob/master/gis/qgis/h3-grid-from-layer.py#L55, the code is `mylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(area_of_interest)[0]`. It means `QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(area_of_interest)` is an empty list `[]` and you can't get the first element with `[0]`. That's why it throws an error

Comment: Thanks Thomas. That bug is now fixed, and a couple more besides. Results posted at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408312/108

Answer (score 6):

*I adapted @ThomasG77's 30 day challenge script into something that can be run from the Qgis processing toolbox.*

**Using Uber's [H3 hex grid system](https://h3geo.org/) in Qgis**

https://github.com/maphew/code/tree/master/gis/qgis - h3-grid-from-layer.py

### Usage

*after [Preparation](https://github.com/maphew/code/blob/master/gis/qgis/h3-in-qgis.md#preparation) has been completed*

From Qgis:

1. Select a template layer in table of contents to get extent from

   1. Optionally select specific features
2. *Processing tool box >> Open existing script: [h3-grid-from-layer.py](https://github.com/maphew/code/blob/master/gis/qgis/h3-grid-from-layer.py)*
3. OR: *Plugins >> Python console >> Open editor >> load script: [h3-grid-from-layer.py](https://github.com/maphew/code/blob/master/gis/qgis/h3-grid-from-layer.py)*
4. Edit variables (particularly min/max resolution levels)
5. Run

There is an error message of "it seems there is no valid script to run", but it works anyway.

[image: screenshot: select extents layer, open script]
[image: screenshot: edit min/max hexes]
[image: screenshot: result]

Answer (score 1):

There's the official https://github.com/uber/h3-py

> Python bindings for H3, a hierarchical hexagonal geospatial indexing system https://uber.github.io/h3/

but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: And https://github.com/conda-forge/h3-py-feedstock/ the conda package

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Create Grid` tool in QGIS, and select hexagons.

For a more thorough, but still brief walk-through, see [Jonathan Soma's blog](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2018/qgis/grid/).

(This is for creating a hex grid, it will not be specific to Uber's H3 grids. If you know the positioning and spacing of that grid you could use those numbers with this tool.)