# Aggregating points using hexabinning in QGIS using Uber H3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, h3, hexagon-binning

I have been trying to aggregate points in QGIS for couple of weeks now.
I am developing a small plugin that should allow simple Hexabinning using Uber's h3 plugin.
Upon clicking the hexabinning button, the following output should be shown.
The output is achieved using the qgis-h3-toolkit-plugin: https://github.com/arongergely/qgis-h3-toolkit-plugin

[image]

However, I have found it very hard to integrate code from this plugin.
I have been instantiating all the three classes and calling their functions, but there are so many  different parameters. See the three classes and functions here https://github.com/arongergely/qgis-h3-toolkit-plugin/blob/main/h3_toolkit/processing/algorithms.py

In my plugin, I have a slider which takes the hexabinning resolution input from the user. Then upon clicking the 'Bin' button, it should call a script/function and the above output should be shown. I am trying to write is a simple script that shows the density of points in hexagons.

I have run the following script: it displays the hexagons, but does not show density
(from https://github.com/maphew/mhwcode/blob/1ef8338e20ff24ddbe741af225e556b9d81ec416/gis/qgis/h3-grid-from-layer.py)

```
# START BINNING    
def binning_function(self):
    # self.hextest = HexTest()
    # ed = self.hextest.begin()
    # er = self.hextest.run()        
    print('binning function')

    self.debug = False

    ###---------- Edit these variables ----------
    # Min & max h3 resolution levels, from 0 to 15 (global to sub-meter)
    # High resolutions over broad areas can be slow and consume a lot of storage space
    # https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/restable
    # Resolution 7 is ~2,000m across, 9 is ~320m across, 11 is ~45m (in YT Albers)
    self.min_resolution = 0
    self.max_resolution = 9

    # Output files are {prefix}_{resolution}: Hex_3, Hex_4, ...
    self.out_name_prefix = "Hex"

    self.geographic_coordsys = "EPSG:4617"  # e.g. WGS84, NAD83(CSRS)
    self.output_projection = "EPSG:3579"  # placeholder, not currently used
    # --------------------------------------------

    projectPath = os.path.dirname(QgsProject.instance().fileName())
    self.geo_csrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(self.geographic_coordsys)
    self.out_csrs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(self.output_projection)

    dataPath = os.path.join(projectPath, "data/")
    if not os.path.exists(dataPath):
        os.mkdir(dataPath)

    #instead of chooser, just use active layer, and selected features within that layer
    self.mylayer = iface.activeLayer()
    if self.mylayer.selectedFeatures():
        params = {'INPUT':self.mylayer, 'OUTPUT':'memory:sel'}
        self.mylayer = processing.run("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", params)["OUTPUT"]
        if self.debug:
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.mylayer)

    self.run()

def log(self, item):
    return QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(item))


def proj_to_geo(self, in_layer):
    """Project to geographic coordinate system, in memory.
    H3 needs all coordinates in decimal degrees"""
    params = {
        "INPUT": self.mylayer,
        "TARGET_CRS": self.geographic_coordsys,
        "OUTPUT": "memory:dd_",
    }
    geo_lyr = processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", params)["OUTPUT"]
    if self.debug:
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(geo_lyr)
    return geo_lyr


def poly_from_extent(self, layer):
    """Return polygon as coordinate list from layer's extent
    Ex:
        [(-142.0, 74.0), (-115.0, 74.0), (-115.0, 54.0), (-142.0, 54.0)]

    Adapted from
    https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245811/getting-layer-extent-in-pyqgis
    """
    ext = layer.extent()
    xmin = ext.xMinimum()
    xmax = ext.xMaximum()
    ymin = ext.yMinimum()
    ymax = ext.yMaximum()
    return [(xmin, ymax), (xmax, ymax), (xmax, ymin), (xmin, ymin)]


def hexes_within_layer_extent(self, layer, level):
    """Return list of HexID within layer's extent
    In: qgis layer object, hex resolution level (0-15)
    Out: ['8412023ffffffff', '84029d5ffffffff', '8413a93ffffffff']
    """
    ext_poly = self.poly_from_extent(layer)
    hex_ids = set(h3.polyfill_polygon(ext_poly, res=level, lnglat_order=True))
    self.log(f"Hex IDs within extent poly: {str(len(hex_ids))}")
    return hex_ids

def run(self):
    geo_layer = self.proj_to_geo(self.mylayer)


    # For each resolution level fetch geometry of each hex feature and write to shapefile with id
    for res in range(self.min_resolution, self.max_resolution + 1):
        self.log("Resolution: {res}")
        fields = QgsFields()
        fields.append(QgsField("id", QVariant.String))
        shpfile = os.path.join(self.dataPath, f"{self.out_name_prefix}_{res}.shp")
        writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(
            shpfile, "UTF8", fields, QgsWkbTypes.Polygon, driverName="ESRI Shapefile"
        )
        features = []
        for id in set(self.hexes_within_layer_extent(geo_layer, res)):
            f = QgsFeature()
            f.setGeometry(
                QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY(
                    [
                        # note reversing back to X,Y
                        [QgsPointXY(c[1], c[0]) for c in h3.h3_to_geo_boundary(id)]
                    ]
                )
            )
            f.setAttributes([id])
            if self.debug:
                self.log(f"Hex: {id} " + str(h3.h3_to_geo_boundary(id)))
            features.append(f)
        writer.addFeatures(features)
        del writer
        self.log("Features out: " + str(len(features)))

        processing.run("qgis:definecurrentprojection", {"INPUT": shpfile, "CRS": self.geo_csrs})

        layer = QgsVectorLayer(shpfile, f"{self.out_name_prefix} {res}", "ogr")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
# END BINNING
```

When the above binning_function() procedure is called from my plugin, the following is output. **Only the hexabins are shown. I would like to see the counts for each hexabin, and the output should be the same as the first output I have posted.**

**The count function**
There is count performed in lines 54-62 of this script: https://github.com/ThomasG77/30DayMapChallenge/blob/master/day4_hexagons/data/h3-processing.py

There is also count performed starting from line 497 of the H3-toolkit here
https://github.com/arongergely/qgis-h3-toolkit-plugin/blob/main/h3_toolkit/processing/algorithms.py
(see lines 666-715)

Also, I just want one layer created as output - not the 0-9 layers. The output should be based on hexabinning value chosen by the user through a QT horizontal slider.

[image]

My dataset: https://mapsafe.xyz/all_clusters_kamloops.zip

Related Post:
[Using Uber H3 hexagon grids in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310555/using-uber-h3-hexagon-grids-in-qgis)